# How to use SQL Sum(Max()) function

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do

```
Select Sum(Max(IsNull(c.CapacityCost, 0)))
```

but it does not work. How can I do that?

Error messages:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

My code:

```
Select 
Max(IsNull(c.CapacityCost, 0)) Company c
```

Comment: >>>Sum(Max(IsNull(sid.CapacityCost,0))) in the description is not present in your code

Comment: @ sepupic I tried it does not work.It is my purpose

Comment: ...and the problem is there, you use aggregate within another aggregate that is not permitted, andd the error tells you about it: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @ sepupic In code Max(IsNull(sid.CapacityCost,0)) but I want to work as Sum(Max(IsNull(sid.CapacityCost,0))) like that,with this logic

Comment: @sepupic so what can I do?How can I write it?

Comment: This changes nothing: you cannot use an aggregate within another aggregate

Comment: Are you sure you need sum of max, groupped by the same fields?

Comment: the thing is: when you do the first aggregate, you already has ONE, only one value per group

Comment: Think about this: when you group by date, companyid, you will have 1 one value, or max, or sum. In first case, when you ask server for max, for every company and every date you'll have max cost, it will be one value. What do you want to do with it? if you then ask server for a sum, or you need not group, or, if you group by company,date again you'll get the same value, it will give you a sum of the one value(that is max value) for given company, date. So this is an errorin the logic

Comment: What are you trying to get?   You need to add sample data and desired results to make your question understandable.

Answer (score 0):

To get what (I think) you want to achieve, you need to use a subquery.  Something along the lines of:

```
declare @company table(
CapacityCost int,
CompanyID int,
CompanyName varchar(20),
Country char(2))

INSERT INTO @company VALUES (20, 1, 'dduck inc', 'us')
INSERT INTO @company VALUES (25, 2, 'dduck plc', 'uk')
INSERT INTO @company VALUES (10, 3, 'mmouse inc', 'us')
INSERT INTO @company VALUES (35, 4, 'mmouse plc', 'uk')
INSERT INTO @company VALUES (15, 5, 'rrabbit inc', 'us')
INSERT INTO @company VALUES (30, 6, 'rrabbit plc', 'uk')

SELECT SUM(MaxCC) 
FROM 
(SELECT MAX(CapacityCost) AS MaxCC, Country FROM @company GROUP BY Country) m
```

When asking SQL questions here, it is always useful to provide some sample data and an illustration of the result set that you want.  That makes it far easier for people to give you help.  As you can see here, I have included in my answer some data and a table structure.  You do not need to give us real data or exactly the same table structure, just enough to illustrate what you are trying to get.